# Ending the scourge of spaces and control characters in filenames

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems

I hate spaces in filenames.  It's a bad plan.  I just don't want 'em.

They make shell scripting tedious, cause security problems, and are just generally annoying.

At one point, I wrote a fuse filesystem which I could mount over my home directory to protect it from this menace, and it worked pretty well.  Each entry which took a pathname simply replaced anything that triggered `isspace(ch)` with either an underscore or a `%\d\d\d` sequence like urlencoding.  It worked fine, though it was a little slow, and surprisingly did not break programs like chrome and firefox (the worse offenders). They kept asking for and creating filenames with spaces, and I kept giving them filenames without.

That code got lost in the mists of time, and now I've got a wild hair about it again. This time, I'd like to hack the kernel itself, rather than using fuse.

So the question is, what is the best way to attack the problem if I am going to hack the kernel itself?  I'm looking at functions like `kern_path` and `file_lookup`, and making some sense of them, but it's a lot more complex than my fuse driver, which simply took its arguments, debauched them, and passed them on.

Comment: Crazy. Maybe hack all file creation syscalls (creat,mkdir, link,mknod, symlink etc) to do the substitution? `git grep SYSCALL_DEFINE fs/*.c` should give you the entire list. But maybe its better to intercept these syscalls even _before_  they enter the kernel using LD_PRELOAD hacks?

Comment: Nuke Redmond...

Comment: I have considered an LD_PRELOAD hack.  I know how to do that one, and I want to test more than one approach, for my education, and also for comparison.

Comment: @itisravi `LD_PRELOAD` does *not* help you intercept syscalls. It's only useful to intercept function calls to library wrappers of such syscalls. If a program does raw syscalls by its own (e.g. is optimized to do so) then you cannot catch that with `LD_PRELOAD`. You'd be better off running everything under `seccomp` at that point.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli You are right about raw syscall invocation. I'm not too knowledgeable in `seccomp`.

Comment: I have no idea what seccomp is, but I intend to find out.  Thanks for the tip.

And I think you're right about LD_PRELOAD.  I'd have to hack libc and recompile, since it's all done with processor magic.